# Given $x = \sqrt[4]{x^{3}+6x^{2}}$, determine whether the sum of all possible roots of $x$ is equal to $1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Given $$x = \sqrt[4]{x^{3}+6x^{2}}$$

Quantity $A$: Sum of all possible roots of $x$

Quantity $B$: $1$

My solution: I've taken fourth power on both sides of the equation to get $$x^{4} = x^{3} + 6x^{2}.$$

Rearranging and factorizing $x^{2}$ gives $$x^{2}(x^{2} - x - 6) = 0.$$
Further factorizing gives $$x^{2}(x-3)(x+2) = 0.$$

So the roots of $x$ are $0$,$-2$,and $3$.

So the sum of the roots is $1$. Thus, my answer is $C$ $(A=B)$.

But the answer in the practice test was $A$. Why is this so?

Comment: Are all the $x$'s you find actual solutions?  Do some lead to fourth roots of negative numbers?  Are the signs right for the $x$'s you find?

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, you don't say "root of $x$". If you want, $x$ *is a root of the equation*. But a root of $x$ would mean something like $\sqrt[n]{x}$ (a *root* of the equation $?\ ^n=x$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Any root $x$ of your original equation
$$x = \sqrt[4]{x^{3}+6x^{2}}$$
should be non-negative because the right-hand side is a non-negative function.

P.S. Notice that by taking fourth power on both sides you found the roots also of the equation
$$-x = \sqrt[4]{x^{3}+6x^{2}}.$$

Comment: Yes, I know that but if $x=-2$, the right-hand side is still positive, no?

Comment: Yes, but it is not equal to the left-hand side!

Comment: Oops! forgot that LHS=RHS. They equal though? If $x=-2$ the $LHS = 16$ and $RHS = (-2)^{3} + 6(-2)^{2} = 16$. Is it correct?

Comment: @OGC In the original equation for $x=-2$ we get $-2=\sqrt[4]{16}=2$.    It should be clear now that the root $−2$ is not acceptable.

Comment: I see it makes sense if I look at the LHS, which can't be negative as the RHS is non-negative. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$-2$ is not a solution of $x = \sqrt[4]{x^{3}+6x^{2}}$.